# How to design vocals like that? [chopped/pitched/reverb]

Tags: reverb, vocals, pitch

https://soundcloud.com/orlogin/dead-sea

In 0:37 - u can hear vocals.
How they were edited so that they sound so deep and excellent?

They are chopped into melody, dipped in reverb effect, fades added, delays, pitched up/down and ....what else? I can't get result like this...

Here is tutorial with similar effect on vocal but it's not exactly that :(

Anybody had experience with vocals like that?

I'll be very grateful.
Regards

Comment: The answer is: patience and a good taste. Really, it's all/mostly manually edited, to taste. The program doesn't matter, nor do the plug-ins, because it can all be done with even a basic audio editor that has parameter automation. Patience and practice is all that's needed and a taste for what sounds nice.

Comment: Yeah that's for sure :) But aside from the melodic arrangement and the sense of taste. How to get this special vocal tone...it's repeated in so many songs :O Maybe I'm pitching wrong, maybe I should have sample in appropriate note...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Ableton I would suggest that you experiment with the Drum Rack to achieve such effect. Try to get an acapella of like one singed sentence or even better record yourself singing (don't worry about lyrics, gibberish should work fine) and pitch it up like 5 semitones; then cut the different words and syllables and put them in different drum rack slots.

Then try to play around with the pitch of each different sample to get different notes and textures and write or play simple riffs with your keyboard, and I think you should get something like that !

I tried to be clear, let me know if you need more info. :)

Comment: To make this easier...Should I start work with vocals at first and then fit bassline etc. to it?

Comment: Hmm nah I don't think it matters in which order you go, the more important is that you find a way to make it work for you and get what you want ! The key is to chop every word or syllabe I think, then try putting them on the grid in a random way at first and adjust until you get something musical!

Answer (score 0):

Working with sampled vocal snippets like this is as much to do with the underlying harmonies as it is to do with the melodic arrangements you come up with. The vocals should fit in the grander scheme of the pitch collection being used and not the literal chords/harmony. Once you get that fit its just a case of pitching and tuning your samples to into unexpected articulations, and using a big reverb.

Comment: Thank u Daniel.
Have u ever seen a tutorial for actions like that? :) I dunno even how to start...